# Jasper report can't find package net.sf.jasperreports.engine

Tags: java, weblogic, jasper-reports

I have a j2ee application using spring framework. I am trying to export jasper reports to xml, pdf and xhtml files. I am using eclipse ide with plugin for weblogic server and for apache tomcat server. It works fine when I run it on server(in eclipse) and choosing Tomcat as server. But when I try to run it on server(in eclipse) now choosing weblogic server I get an error. Heres the full stack trace of the error

```
> net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException:
> Errors were encountered when compiling
> report expressions class file:
> C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\wl_server\TestJasper_1262789093368_66389.java:4:
> package net.sf.jasperreports.engine
> does not exist import
> net.sf.jasperreports.engine.*; ^
> C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\wl_server\TestJasper_1262789093368_66389.java:5:
> package
> net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill does
> not exist。 import
> net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.*; ^
> C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\wl_server\TestJasper_1262789093368_66389.java:13:
> package net.sf.jasperreports.engine
> does not exist。 import
> net.sf.jasperreports.engine.*; ^
> C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\wl_server\TestJasper_1262789093368_66389.java:15:
> package
> net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data does
> not exist。 import
> net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.*; ^
> C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\wl_server\TestJasper_1262789093368_66389.java:21:
> cannot find symbol。  symbol: class
> JREvaluator public class
> TestJasper_1262789093368_66389 extends
> JREvaluator ^
> C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\wl_server\TestJasper_1262789093368_66389.java:28:
> cannot find symbol。  symbol: class
> JRFillParameter location :
> TestJasper_1262789093368_66389 の class
> private JRFillParameter
> parameter_REPORT_LOCALE = null; ^
> C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\wl_server\TestJasper_1262789093368_66389.java:29:
> cannot find symbol。  symbol: class
> JRFillParameter location :
> TestJasper_1262789093368_66389 の class
> private JRFillParameter
> parameter_JASPER_REPORT = null; ^
> C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\wl_server\TestJasper_1262789093368_66389.java:30:
> cannot find symbol。  symbol: class
> JRFillParameter location :
> TestJasper_1262789093368_66389 の class
> private JRFillParameter
> parameter_REPORT_VIRTUALIZER = null; ^
```

C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\wl_server\TestJasper_1262789093368_66389.java:40:

> cannot find symbol。  symbol: class
>   JRFillParameter location :
>   TestJasper_1262789093368_66389 の class
>   private JRFillParameter
>   parameter_title = null; ^
>   C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\wl_server\TestJasper_1262789093368_66389.java:41:
>   cannot find symbol。  symbol: class
>   JRFillParameter location :
>   TestJasper_1262789093368_66389 の class
>   private JRFillParameter
>   parameter_REPORT_FORMAT_FACTORY =
>   null; ^
>   C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\wl_server\TestJasper_1262789093368_66389.java:42:
>   cannot find symbol。  symbol: class
>   JRFillParameter location :
>   TestJasper_1262789093368_66389 の class
>   private JRFillParameter
>   parameter_REPORT_MAX_COUNT = null; ^
>   C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\wl_server\TestJasper_1262789093368_66389.java:43:
>   cannot find symbol。  symbol: class
>   JRFillParameter location :
>   TestJasper_1262789093368_66389 の class
>   private JRFillParameter
>   parameter_REPORT_TEMPLATES = null; ^
>   C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\wl_server\TestJasper_1262789093368_66389.java:44:
>   cannot find symbol。  symbol: class
>   JRFillParameter location :
>   TestJasper_1262789093368_66389 の class
>   private JRFillParameter
>   parameter_REPORT_RESOURCE_BUNDLE =
>   null; ^
>   C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\wl_server\TestJasper_1262789093368_66389.java:45:
>   cannot find symbol。  symbol: class
>   JRFillField location :
>   TestJasper_1262789093368_66389 の class
>   private JRFillField field_SERV_ID =
>   null; ^
>   C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\wl_server\TestJasper_1262789093368_66389.java:46:
>   cannot find symbol。  symbol: class
>   JRFillField location :
>   TestJasper_1262789093368_66389 の class
>   private JRFillField
>   field_EMP_FIRSTNAME = null; ^
>   C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\wl_server\TestJasper_1262789093368_66389.java:47:
>   cannot find symbol。  symbol: class
>   JRFillField location :
>   TestJasper_1262789093368_66389 の class
>   private JRFillField field_EMP_ID =
>   null; ^
>   C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\wl_server\TestJasper_1262789093368_66389.java:48:
>   cannot find symbol。  symbol: class
>   JRFillField location :
>   TestJasper_1262789093368_66389 の class
>   private JRFillField field_EMP_SALARY =
>   null; ^
>   C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\wl_server\TestJasper_1262789093368_66389.java:49:
>   cannot find symbol。  symbol: class
>   JRFillField location :
>   TestJasper_1262789093368_66389 の class
>   private JRFillField field_EMP_SURNAME
>   = null; ^ C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\wl_server\TestJasper_1262789093368_66389.java:50:
>   cannot find symbol。  symbol: class
>   JRFillField location :
>   TestJasper_1262789093368_66389 の class
>   private JRFillField field_SERV_NAME =
>   null; ^
>   C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\wl_server\TestJasper_1262789093368_66389.java:51:
>   cannot find symbol。  symbol: class
>   JRFillVariable location :
>   TestJasper_1262789093368_66389 の class
>   private JRFillVariable
>   variable_PAGE_NUMBER = null; ^
>   C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\wl_server\TestJasper_1262789093368_66389.java:52:
>   cannot find symbol。  symbol: class
>   JRFillVariable location :
>   TestJasper_1262789093368_66389 の class
>   private JRFillVariable
>   variable_COLUMN_NUMBER = null; ^
>   C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\wl_server\TestJasper_1262789093368_66389.java:53:
>   cannot find symbol。  symbol: class
>   JRFillVariable location :
>   TestJasper_1262789093368_66389 の class
>   private JRFillVariable
>   variable_REPORT_COUNT = null; ^
>   C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\wl_server\TestJasper_1262789093368_66389.java:54:
>   cannot find symbol。  symbol: class
>   JRFillVariable location :
>   TestJasper_1262789093368_66389 の class
>   private JRFillVariable
>   variable_PAGE_COUNT = null; ^
>   C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\wl_server\TestJasper_1262789093368_66389.java:55:
>   cannot find symbol。  symbol: class
>   JRFillVariable location :
>   TestJasper_1262789093368_66389 の class
>   private JRFillVariable
>   variable_COLUMN_COUNT = null; ^
>   C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\wl_server\TestJasper_1262789093368_66389.java:56:
>   cannot find symbol。  symbol: class
>   JRFillVariable location :
>   TestJasper_1262789093368_66389 の class
>   private JRFillVariable
>   variable_Service_COUNT = null; ^
>   C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\wl_server\TestJasper_1262789093368_66389.java:57:
>   cannot find symbol。  symbol: class
>   JRFillVariable location :
>   TestJasper_1262789093368_66389 の class
>   private JRFillVariable variable_total
>   = null; ^ C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\wl_server\TestJasper_1262789093368_66389.java:58:
>   cannot find symbol。  symbol: class
>   JRFillVariable location :
>   TestJasper_1262789093368_66389 の class
>   private JRFillVariable
>   variable_service_salary_subtotal =
>   null; ^
>   C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\wl_server\TestJasper_1262789093368_66389.java:81:
>   cannot find symbol。  symbol: class
>   JRFillParameter location :
>   TestJasper_1262789093368_66389 の class
>   parameter_REPORT_LOCALE =
>   (JRFillParameter)pm.get("REPORT_LOCALE");
>   ^
>   C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\wl_server\TestJasper_1262789093368_66389.java:82:
>   cannot find symbol。  symbol: class
>   JRFillParameter location :
>   TestJasper_1262789093368_66389 の class
>   parameter_JASPER_REPORT =
>   (JRFillParameter)pm.get("JASPER_REPORT");
>   ^
>   C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\wl_server\TestJasper_1262789093368_66389.java:83:
>   cannot find symbol。  symbol: class
>   JRFillParameter location :
>   TestJasper_1262789093368_66389 の class
>   parameter_REPORT_VIRTUALIZER =
>   (JRFillParameter)pm.get("REPORT_VIRTUALIZER");
>   ^
>   C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\wl_server\TestJasper_1262789093368_66389.java:84:
>   cannot find symbol。  symbol: class
>   JRFillParameter location :
>   TestJasper_1262789093368_66389 の class
>   parameter_REPORT_TIME_ZONE =
>   (JRFillParameter)pm.get("REPORT_TIME_ZONE");
>   ^
>   C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\wl_server\TestJasper_1262789093368_66389.java:85:
>   cannot find symbol。  symbol: class
>   JRFillParameter location :
>   TestJasper_1262789093368_66389 の class
>   parameter_REPORT_FILE_RESOLVER =
>   (JRFillParameter)pm.get("REPORT_FILE_RESOLVER");
>   ^
>   C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\wl_server\TestJasper_1262789093368_66389.java:86:
>   cannot find symbol。  symbol: class
>   JRFillParameter location :
>   TestJasper_1262789093368_66389 の class
>   parameter_REPORT_SCRIPTLET =
>   (JRFillParameter)pm.get("REPORT_SCRIPTLET");
>   ^
>   C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\wl_server\TestJasper_1262789093368_66389.java:87:
>   cannot find symbol。  symbol: class
>   JRFillParameter location :
>   TestJasper_1262789093368_66389 の class
>   parameter_REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP =
>   (JRFillParameter)pm.get("REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP");
>   ^
>   C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\wl_server\TestJasper_1262789093368_66389.java:88:
>   cannot find symbol。  symbol: class
>   JRFillParameter location :
>   TestJasper_1262789093368_66389 の class
>   parameter_REPORT_CONNECTION =
>   (JRFillParameter)pm.get("REPORT_CONNECTION");
>   ^
>   C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\wl_server\TestJasper_1262789093368_66389.java:89:
>   cannot find symbol。  symbol: class
>   JRFillParameter location :
>   TestJasper_1262789093368_66389 の class
>   parameter_REPORT_CLASS_LOADER =
>   (JRFillParameter)pm.get("REPORT_CLASS_LOADER");
>   ^
>   C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\wl_server\TestJasper_1262789093368_66389.java:90:
>   cannot find symbol。  symbol: class
>   JRFillParameter location :
>   TestJasper_1262789093368_66389 の class
>   parameter_REPORT_DATA_SOURCE =
>   (JRFillParameter)pm.get("REPORT_DATA_SOURCE");
>   ^
>   C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\wl_server\TestJasper_1262789093368_66389.java:91:
>   cannot find symbol。  symbol: class
>   JRFillParameter location :
>   TestJasper_1262789093368_66389 の class
>   parameter_REPORT_URL_HANDLER_FACTORY =
>   (JRFillParameter)pm.get("REPORT_URL_HANDLER_FACTORY");
>   ^
>   C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\wl_server\TestJasper_1262789093368_66389.java:92:
>   cannot find symbol。  symbol: class
>   JRFillParameter location :
>   TestJasper_1262789093368_66389 の class
>   parameter_IS_IGNORE_PAGINATION =
>   (JRFillParameter)pm.get("IS_IGNORE_PAGINATION");
>   ^
>   C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\wl_server\TestJasper_1262789093368_66389.java:93:
>   cannot find symbol。  symbol: class
>   JRFillParameter location :
>   TestJasper_1262789093368_66389 の class
>   parameter_title =
>   (JRFillParameter)pm.get("title"); ^
>   C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\wl_server\TestJasper_1262789093368_66389.java:94:
>   cannot find symbol。  symbol: class
>   JRFillParameter location :
>   TestJasper_1262789093368_66389 の class
>   parameter_REPORT_FORMAT_FACTORY =
>   (JRFillParameter)pm.get("REPORT_FORMAT_FACTORY");
>   ^
>   C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\wl_server\TestJasper_1262789093368_66389.java:95:
>   cannot find symbol。  symbol: class
>   JRFillParameter location :
>   TestJasper_1262789093368_66389 の class
>   parameter_REPORT_MAX_COUNT =
>   (JRFillParameter)pm.get("REPORT_MAX_COUNT");
>   ^
>   C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\wl_server\TestJasper_1262789093368_66389.java:96:
>   cannot find symbol。  symbol: class
>   JRFillParameter location :
>   TestJasper_1262789093368_66389 の class
>   parameter_REPORT_TEMPLATES =
>   (JRFillParameter)pm.get("REPORT_TEMPLATES");
>   ^
>   C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\wl_server\TestJasper_1262789093368_66389.java:97:
>   cannot find symbol。  symbol: class
>   JRFillParameter location :
>   TestJasper_1262789093368_66389 の class
>   parameter_REPORT_RESOURCE_BUNDLE =
>   (JRFillParameter)pm.get("REPORT_RESOURCE_BUNDLE");
>   ^
>   C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\wl_server\TestJasper_1262789093368_66389.java:106:
>   cannot find symbol。  symbol: class
>   JRFillField location :
>   TestJasper_1262789093368_66389 の class
>   field_SERV_ID =
>   (JRFillField)fm.get("SERV_ID"); ^
>   C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\wl_server\TestJasper_1262789093368_66389.java:107:
>   cannot find symbol。  symbol: class
>   JRFillField location :
>   TestJasper_1262789093368_66389 の class
>   field_EMP_FIRSTNAME =
>   (JRFillField)fm.get("EMP_FIRSTNAME");
>   ^
>   C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\wl_server\TestJasper_1262789093368_66389.java:108:
>   cannot find symbol。  symbol: class
>   JRFillField location :
>   TestJasper_1262789093368_66389 の class
>   field_EMP_ID =
>   (JRFillField)fm.get("EMP_ID"); ^
>   C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\wl_server\TestJasper_1262789093368_66389.java:109:
>   cannot find symbol。  symbol: class
>   JRFillField location :
>   TestJasper_1262789093368_66389 の class
>   field_EMP_SALARY =
>   (JRFillField)fm.get("EMP_SALARY"); ^
>   C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\wl_server\TestJasper_1262789093368_66389.java:110:
>   cannot find symbol。  symbol: class
>   JRFillField location :
>   TestJasper_1262789093368_66389 の class
>   field_EMP_SURNAME =
>   (JRFillField)fm.get("EMP_SURNAME"); ^
>   C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\wl_server\TestJasper_1262789093368_66389.java:111:
>   cannot find symbol。  symbol: class
>   JRFillField location :
>   TestJasper_1262789093368_66389 の class
>   field_SERV_NAME =
>   (JRFillField)fm.get("SERV_NAME"); ^
>   C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\wl_server\TestJasper_1262789093368_66389.java:120:
>   cannot find symbol。  symbol: class
>   JRFillVariable location :
>   TestJasper_1262789093368_66389 の class
>   variable_PAGE_NUMBER =
>   (JRFillVariable)vm.get("PAGE_NUMBER");
>   ^
>   C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\wl_server\TestJasper_1262789093368_66389.java:121:
>   cannot find symbol。  symbol: class
>   JRFillVariable location :
>   TestJasper_1262789093368_66389 の class
>   variable_COLUMN_NUMBER =
>   (JRFillVariable)vm.get("COLUMN_NUMBER");
>   ^
>   C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\wl_server\TestJasper_1262789093368_66389.java:122:
>   cannot find symbol。  symbol: class
>   JRFillVariable location :
>   TestJasper_1262789093368_66389 の class
>   variable_REPORT_COUNT =
>   (JRFillVariable)vm.get("REPORT_COUNT");
>   ^
>   C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\wl_server\TestJasper_1262789093368_66389.java:123:
>   cannot find symbol。  symbol: class
>   JRFillVariable location :
>   TestJasper_1262789093368_66389 の class
>   variable_PAGE_COUNT =
>   (JRFillVariable)vm.get("PAGE_COUNT");
>   ^
>   C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\wl_server\TestJasper_1262789093368_66389.java:124:
>   cannot find symbol。  symbol: class
>   JRFillVariable location :
>   TestJasper_1262789093368_66389 の class
>   variable_COLUMN_COUNT =
>   (JRFillVariable)vm.get("COLUMN_COUNT");
>   ^
>   C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\wl_server\TestJasper_1262789093368_66389.java:125:
>   cannot find symbol。  symbol: class
>   JRFillVariable location :
>   TestJasper_1262789093368_66389 の class
>   variable_Service_COUNT =
>   (JRFillVariable)vm.get("Service_COUNT");
>   ^
>   C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\wl_server\TestJasper_1262789093368_66389.java:126:
>   cannot find symbol。  symbol: class
>   JRFillVariable location :
>   TestJasper_1262789093368_66389 の class
>   variable_total =
>   (JRFillVariable)vm.get("total"); ^
>   C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\wl_server\TestJasper_1262789093368_66389.java:127:
>   cannot find symbol。  symbol: class
>   JRFillVariable location :
>   TestJasper_1262789093368_66389 の class
>   variable_service_salary_subtotal =
>   (JRFillVariable)vm.get("service_salary_subtotal");
>   ^ エラー 67 個
>
> at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractCompiler.compileReport(JRAbstractCompiler.java:195)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReport(JasperCompileManager.java:219)
>   at
>   jp.co.anicom.framework.reportutil.report.generateReport(report.java:39)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>   at
>   org.jboss.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:328)
>   at
>   org.jboss.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:273)
>   at
>   org.jboss.el.parser.AstMethodSuffix.getValue(AstMethodSuffix.java:59)
>   at
>   org.jboss.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:67)
>   at
>   org.jboss.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:186)
>   at
>   org.springframework.binding.expression.el.BindingValueExpression.getValue(BindingValueExpression.java:54)
>   at
>   org.springframework.binding.expression.el.ELExpression.getValue(ELExpression.java:54)
>   at
>   org.springframework.webflow.action.EvaluateAction.doExecute(EvaluateAction.java:77)
>   at
>   org.springframework.webflow.action.AbstractAction.execute(AbstractAction.java:188)
>   at
>   org.springframework.webflow.execution.AnnotatedAction.execute(AnnotatedAction.java:145)
>   at
>   org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor.execute(ActionExecutor.java:51)
>   at
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.ActionList.execute(ActionList.java:155)
>   at
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.start(Flow.java:534)
>   at
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.start(FlowExecutionImpl.java:364)
>   at
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.start(FlowExecutionImpl.java:222)
>   at
>   org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.launchExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:140)
>   at
>   org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:193)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:875)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:807)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:571)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:501)
>   at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
>   at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
>   at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
>   at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
>   at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:292)
>   at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
>   at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:378)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.ui.SessionFixationProtectionFilter.doFilterHttp(SessionFixationProtectionFilter.java:67)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilterHttp(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:101)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:105)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:116)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.wrapper.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilterHttp(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:91)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.ui.basicauth.BasicProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(BasicProcessingFilter.java:174)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:278)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.ui.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilterHttp(LogoutFilter.java:89)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilterHttp(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:235)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.concurrent.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilterHttp(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:99)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:175)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:236)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
>   at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:96)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
>   at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
>   at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
>   at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
>   at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3588)
>   at
>   weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
>   at
>   weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:121)
>   at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2200)
>   at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2106)
>   at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1428)
>   at
>   weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201)
>   at
>   weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173)

I had checked the jar files needed for jasper report and i think i have included all in my lib.
Weblogic.xml

```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <wls:weblogic-web-app
> xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"
> xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
> xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
> http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd
> http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app
> http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.0/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
>     <wls:container-descriptor>
>         <wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>true</wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>
>     </wls:container-descriptor>
>     <wls:weblogic-version>10.3.1</wls:weblogic-version>
>     <wls:fast-swap>
>         <wls:enabled>false</wls:enabled>
>     </wls:fast-swap> </wls:weblogic-web-app>
```

Comment: How did you solve this issue ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29753457/jasper-reports-package-net-sf-jasperreports-engine-does-not-exist-exception-in Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like one of the Jasper Reports' jars is missing from the classpath on the WebLogic environment. Check the documentation for your application server, probably you could configure it to log class loading operations and get more information to solve the issue. I know [how to debug class loading issues on OC4J](http://wuhai.wordpress.com/2008/01/21/how-to-debug-oc4j-1013-class-loading-issue/) (I work with OC4J and solved problems like this enabling logging class loading events and looking at the logs). Try to do the same...

I'm not sure, may be the article [Making the Most of WebLogic Classloaders](http://weblogic.sys-con.com/node/42876) also helps you.

Comment: If you were using maven, you also may have had an issue with the configuration of the POM it's self. I've written an article about this: http://theexceptioncatcher.com/blog/2011/09/fixing-classpath-issues-with-jasperreports-j2ee-and-maven/

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem once and it was fixed by including the jdt-compiler jar that is in the JasperReport full project lib.
There is a note on that here: http://www.installationwiki.org/JasperReports (see JDT compiler section).
The error I got was very similar to what I see in your logs.

Answer (score 1):

Check that all the jars required by JasperReports are provided in the `WEB-INF/lib` directory of your war. This doesn't explain why things are working with Tomcat but well.

Here, WebLogic is clearly not able to find the classes from `net.sf.jasperreports.engine.*` in the classpath. Do you see any particular complains in the server logs during startup? Is there any chance you put the required jars in Tomcat's classpath instead of `WEB-INF/lib`?

Comment: I am sure I have my jar in my web-inf/lib. I have this file weblogic.xml in the same location as the web.xml. Where in the application is this being loaded or read? Because currently I can't see any in the application reeading or referencing this file. Content of the file pasted above.

Answer (score 1):

I tried using the below dependency and it is working with weblogic.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>eclipse</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdtcore</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
```